# PI filter (on PSU) and electrolytic capacitors after

Tags: filter

I am designing a small DAC and I want to clean the power supply (it's noisy). I used a PI filter.

However, after the PI filter, I need an electrolytic capacitor (330 µF) to help with some transients. The problem is that the output of PI filter has a capacitor that is in direct correlation with the L...so by adding this electro capacitor I will change that correlation. Any pointers on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra capacitance will obviously change the characteristics (i.e., frequency response) of your Pi filter, but the key is, it won't make it *worse for your application* in any way. Go ahead and hook it up.